# Arithmetic operation is always evaluated as 0

Tags: c#

I'm working on a flocking algorithm and for this I need to have an algrithm for the cohesive force. For this I'm using this line:

```
velocityVector.X = 10 / (distX - distanceBetweenLabels) 
                          * (label.Location.X - ctrl.Location.X);
```

After this line velocitVector.X always equals 0. The distX is always positive. My aim for this is to produce nice cohesion between the particles while still keeping a minimum distance between them.

UPDATE

So thanks for the comments the `10 / (distX - distanceBetweenLabels)` was defaulting to integer caluclation hence equating the whole line to 0.

Comment: Try it with `10.0` instead of `10` - it probably defaults to `int` arithmetic.

Comment: Are the numbers in the denominator integers? An integer divide by any number greater than 10 will result in an integer result of zero - you probably need to use float/double arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10 / (distX - distanceBetweenLabels) 
                      * (label.Location.X - ctrl.Location.X);
```

10 here keeps the expression integer if the denominator turns out to be integer.
Change it to `10.0` or better `10F` for float of `10D` for double precision .

Evaluating the following :

```
var intTest = 10/123;
var floatTest = 10F/123;
var doubleTest = 10D/123;
```

Outputs as  :

```
0
0.08130081
0.0813008130081301
```

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. The `10` does **not** make "the whole expression a integer evaluation". If the variables `distX` and `distanceBetweenLabels` are also integers then the expression `10 / (distX - distanceBetweenLabels)` is computed using integer math. However, if either of `distX` and `distanceBetweenLabels` was a `double` then the expression would evaluate using floating-point math.